# Object classifier does not have a companion object and thus must be initialized here[kotlin]

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, spinner

The problem is comented below.
Android studio is displaying this message with:

-Object
classifier 'Object' does not have a companion object and thus must be initialized here

-selectedItem
unresolved referente: selectedItem

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_training_route)


    val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.S24)
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this,
        R.array.A24,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    ).also { adapter ->
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
    }

    S24.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

            //Problem here
            Object selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)

            if (selectedItem.equals("Red")) {
                sendCommand("1000024")
            }
            //To here
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should be `val selectedItem: Any = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just tried your solution and now I'm getting this message on the dot:
parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type of AdapterView<*>?

Comment: Yup!  Sorry, it should be `parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)` since `parent` is a nullable `AdapterView<*>?`.

Comment: val selectedItem: Any = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)
Now I'm getting a type mismatch message.
Sorry for bothering you, but a really need to get this over

Comment: This is what happens when I type this up without trying.  It's returning a type of `Any?`, not `Any`.

Comment: Now I tried:
val selectedItem: Any? = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) and it worked!
Thank you very much for your help!!
I'm really, really greatful <3

Comment: Glad it worked!  Sorry it took a few steps to get there.